# redirecting existing Access forms to SQL Server

Tags: ms-access-2007

In our organisation, we have Sales Database in Access. The Access database has few forms and few reports. Over time, the Access database has grown. Retrieving records via forms has become slow and cumbersome. 
We have decided to divide the migration two phase – short term and long term. In short term, we want to migrate the Access database to the SQL Server and leave the forms and reports in Access as it is.  I have to link the forms and reports to the SQL Server tables. 
I have successfully migrated the Access database to SQL SERVER using migration assistant tool. I am stuck at changing the forms to talk to the SQL Server. 
My question is – 
Is it possible to change the existing access form to talk to SQL SERVER?
If the above answer is wrong, what are other method I can use to achieve the same objective? 
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to create linked tables within your Access DB to the tables on SQL server, as long as they are named the same as the old local access tables (so get rid of the leading **dbo.**) then you should be ok. There may be a couple of behavioural issues but nothing too bad to overcome.

Answer (score 2):

I belive you can do it by creating "linked tables" with the same name as the original tables.

I've done it using ODBC in the "External Data" on the menu bar, chose "ODBC Database", and then "Link to DataSource, and create linked tables".

When the wizard is finished "it's pretty much forward", just change the table names to the original table names, and the forms should work as "nothing had changed".

Comment: 11 years later, I'd like to say a quick search brought me here, and you are (still) correct. Easy fix.